# Linq to entities nullable int column required?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to do a left outer join between 2 tables, but the resulting query always gives me the error: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'"

my table consists indeed of an Id int column, but my goal is to list entries where the id would be "null" as entries that business still need to create.  the value for this Id property can be 0, that's also fine, but right now i can't do anything with it.  This is the query i currently have:

```
from items in
                        (
                            from x in ctx.SAP_Shippeds select new { MaterialNumber = x.Material, MaterialDescription = x.MaterialDescription })
                            .Concat(from y in ctx.SAP_Ordereds select new { MaterialNumber = y.Material, MaterialDescription = y.MaterialDescription }
                        ).Distinct()
                        join pc in ctx.SAP_CrestronProductCategories on items.MaterialNumber equals pc.MaterialNumber into g
                        from col in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new ViewModelForProductCategory
                        {
                            Id = col.Id,
                            MaterialNumber = col.MaterialNumber,
                            CrestronLvl1Description = col.CrestronLvl1Description,
                            CrestronLvl2Description = col.CrestronLvl2Description,
                            CrestronLvl3Description = col.CrestronLvl3Description,
                            TigLvl1Description = col.TigLvl1Description,
                            TigLvl2Description = col.TigLvl2Description,
                            TigLvl3Description = col.TigLvl3Description
                        });
```

so basically i have a list of orders and invoices.  I want to combine unique (distinct) materialnumbers for these 2 tables in 1 table, and then join these on another table where business will add descriptions for them.
Materialnumers existing in order or shipped table, but not in the description table, should also appear (but then with id being NULL) so i can make it clear that business still needs to enter these.

anyone can help?

Comment: Use (int?) instead of (int) or there is a property in the class ViewModelForProductCategory which you need to change from int to int?

Comment: the viewmodel property is not the problem.  the problem is the int property of the SAP_CrestronProductCategories acoording to the error i get.  and this is an auto numbering column i cannot or want to make nullable

Comment: Did you check with database tool to see if there are nulls in the database?

Comment: there are no null, it is also impossible that there are NULLS because it is the auto numbering key of the table.  the nulls are created because of the outer join, which is what i want, if needed i would be willing to turn the NULL into 0. that would also be fine

Comment: Then you do not want a left outer join.  You are creating a new ViewModelForProductCategory when the right side is null then all the values for col are also null.  Removing the left outer join (g.DefaultIfEmpty) would solve issue.

Comment: More specifically, remove from `into` to `g.DefaultIfEmpty` to create an inner join.

Comment: thanks but i don't want an inner join.  i want a list of descriptions already existing, along with a list of descriptions that still need to be created based on the null items of that outer join.  I can write and visualize in the query exactly what i need, but i can't carry it over to c# the way i want.  I guess it's not possible what i want to do then